# Add a JList/JScrollPane to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, jlist

How to add a `JList`/`JScrollPane` to a `JPanel`?

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring this out, I've created a `JPanel`, and what I want to do is add a list with scroll pane so that I'm able to add/remove elements from it.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction in which to go?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) & especially [Adding Items to and Removing Items from a List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable).  Voting to close.

Answer (score 3):

This is relativly simple question...

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());  
ListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
panel.add(new JScrollPane(new JList(model));
```

You should take the time to read through [Creating a UI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), especially [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)